# Converting JSON file to Parquet file

Tags: json, go

I want to convert my JSON file data into Parquet file format using Golang. Does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

[parquet-go](https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go) library can be used for that. It has an example of [JSONWriter](https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/blob/master/example/json_write.go). Or you can make use of a [schema](https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/blob/master/example/json_schema.go).